# Matchmaking using Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a multiplayer game, So I wanna create a matchmaking feature to connect to a random opponent.

So I wrote the following basic function in Firebase cloud functions for tesitng,

```
exports.matchUser = functions.database.ref('/match/{user}/{id}').onWrite((event) => {
    var user = event.params.user;
    db.ref("matching").limitToFirst(1).once("value" , function(snap) {
        if(snap.exists()){
            snap.forEach(function(userSnap){
                console.log(userSnap.key);
                var opp = userSnap.key;
                var key = db.ref("matched").push().key;
                console.log(key);
                db.ref("matching").child(opp).remove();
                db.ref("matched").child(key).child(user).set(opp);
            })
        }else{
            db.ref("matching").child(user).set(true);
        }
    });
});
```

Then added some dummy users to matching database.

It works fine when I add data to match db one by one.

But when I add multiple data fast using import feature on Firebase console, sometimes the matched user gets repeated.

[image: db example]

The users of db match and matching are same. But when I imported the match database, as you can see user buck3 is repeated three times in matched database.

How can I solve this problem. Need Help..

Comment: In short, you can use transactions.
In detailed, Please go through this [article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/01/google-loteria-realtime-database.html).